# Typescript and JQuery compile error: Cannot find name '$'

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm testing typescript with jquery, but when I compile the test.ts file, it always gives me an error indicating: Cannot find name '$'.

I've already imported jquery & added its definition reference.
If I use `import $ = require("jquery")` in my `test.ts` file, another error "`Cannot find module jquery`" will occur when doing the `tsc` compiling.  However, the JQuery folder already exists within the node_modules folder.

Does anyone know what is the correct way to use jquery in typescript?

Below is my steps:

1. Install jquery using `npm install jquery --save`
2. Install typings & jquery definition using `typings install --global --save dt~jquery`
3. Add jquery reference at top of test.ts `/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./src/wo/tests/test.ts",
    ]
}
```

**test.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />

let test:any=$("div");
```

Comment: How do you compile the project? Also it seems that your `tsconfig.json` definition is wrong. You can't use both `exclude` and `files` (`files` will win in this case, so maybe path is wrong). Also you don't need `/// <reference` if `tsconfig.json` used

Comment: You can refer below link for this solution its work for use $ and query all function in typescript.
Link :
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/typescript-with-jquery/

Answer (score 46):

If you find these errors 90% of the time its because of versioning Problem of @types/jquery

Try running:

```
 npm install jquery --save
```

Then in `app.module.ts`:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Then run:

```
  npm install @types/jquery@2.0.47
```

And you should be ready to go.

Comment: This worked for me although I had to put jquery in a string like `import * as $ from "jquery";`. IntelliJ highlights it grey as an unused import but the app will only compile with this line.

Comment: The last step was what I needed for `jquery@3.3.1`

Comment: Hello @Ignatius Andrew,
It worked, But I am getting some warning like

  `app/app.module.ts[14, 13]: Unused import: '$'`

Comment: Praveen Kumar.. Add a Custom typings to '$' as type 'any', it should dissapear.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if it helps but I solved the same issue for my datepicker.

First I installed jQuery with this command: `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

Then add the dependencies in your angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
            "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
            "styles.css"
        ]

"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
        ]
```

I think adding the jQuery part might work out for you. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery` solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Only this combined with `import * as $ from 'jquery';` solved my issue.

Comment: In angular 6 angular-cli.json becomes angular.json, but there was no need for me to modify scripts section.Just  `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery ` and `import * as $ from 'jquery';` was enough to ng build

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

didn't work for me. Interesting enough,

```
import { ajax, css } from "jquery";
```

actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install and import following package. it will solved for error ("Cannot find name '$'"). Angular version is 7

import 'datatables.net';

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Only Install in Angular file location , then the `ng s` cmd

Answer (score -4):

You probably have some vulnerabilities you need to fix.

Run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details.