# Impossible to deploy Cloud Functions from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm building an Angular + Firebase web app and due to some complex queries I started looking for Cloud Functions from firebase.

My project looks like:

```
MyProject
   |__ node_modules
   |__ src (with app and my complete project)
   |__ some files like tsconfig.json
```

So I add a repertory "functions" and I followed the classic tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

```
MyProject
   |__ node_modules
   |__ src (with app and my complete project)
   |__ some files like tsconfig.json
   |__ functions
           |__ node_modules
           |__ src
```

But problem when using firebase deploy --only functions

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! path E:\Work\MyProject\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Work\MyProject\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

It creates a "%RESOURC_DIR%" folder but there is package.json inside.

Any idea ? Did I do something wrong ?

Versions:
"firebase": "^5.0.4"
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"

Comment: What version of the Firebase CLI are you using?  Did you do anything at all outside of following the exact instructions?

Comment: My bad, forgot to write that:  "firebase": "^5.0.4" "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5". No I didn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349057/7949696  Also, delete the %RESOURCE_DIR% directory that it accidentally created.

Comment: What is the version of the CLI?  Run `firebase --version`.

Comment: @DougStevenson v4.2.1. JamesPoag Thank's ! I'm getting a lot of errors like ../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(191,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequest'. now, I tried to change jquery version to jquery@2.0.47 as I saw (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283236/typescript-and-jquery-compile-error-cannot-find-name) but it hasn't solved my problem !

Comment: Everything you just said doesn't sound related to the original question.

Comment: I followed what said James and it unlocked the situation so you are right it doesn't related to the original question but I'm getting new errors and I don't want to spam SO that's why I was asking here maybe it's just a little thing to do

Comment: If you have a new question, it's always OK to simply ask it separately.  It's more valuable to others if the question and answer aren't buried in comments of an unrelated question.